# Why is my ajaxurl variable showing as undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to use the following code to count  mp3 plays which is in ajax-counter.js on a wordpress plugin

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    console.log(ChurchAdminAjax.ajaxurl);
    $("audio").bind("play", function(){
        console.log(ChurchAdminAjax.ajaxurl);
        var data = {action: "play_count",file_id: $(this).attr("id")};
        $.post(ChurchAdminAjax.ajaxurl, data);
    });
});
```

I've used the following to enqueue and localise that script

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'ca-ajax-request', CHURCH_ADMIN_INCLUDE_URL. 'ajax-counter.js', array( 'jquery' ) )
wp_localize_script( 'ca-ajax-request', 'ChurchAdminAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
```

The first console.log successfully displays the ajaxurl, but the console is showing 
Uncaught ReferenceError: ajaxurl is not defined 
and even when the HTML5 audio is played the second console.log is not shown and the ajax not sent!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code works for me (1st and 2nd logs), but you have a missing semi-colon at the end of `wp_enqueue_script`. **Please**, read the guide [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an empty WP installed on this machine to test so forgive me for guessing here, but some things I did try when debugging a similar problem just the other week:

1. Are you able you `console.log` anything else inside the bind handler? To see if the handler is actually firing.
2. Could there be some other code unbinding your listener after you declared this binding?
3. Have you tried either using `window.ChurchAdminAjax.ajaxurl` or assigning the `ChurchAdminAjax.ajaxurl` to a local variable (inside the ready handler) and using that instead?

Granted, the last one's a bit of a longshot but you'll never know.